# Typescript equivalent to C#'s NotNullWhen

Tags: c#, typescript, null, type-systems, typescript-types

When using non-nullable reference types in C# [you can annotate an input parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) to show that it isn't null, when the method returns false:

```cs
// From string
bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value)

// User code
string? userInput = GetUserInput();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
{
    int messageLength = userInput.Length; // no null check needed.
}
// null check needed on userInput here.
```

Say I have something similar in Typescript:

```js
// Helper method
isNullOrEmpty(s: string | undefined | null): boolean

// User code
const userInput = getUserInput();
if (!isNullOrEmpty(userInput))
{
    const messageLength = userInput.length; // Typescript complains here
}                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to define the `isNullOrEmpty` to help the type system in Typescript figuring out that the input parameter isn't null or undefined, when the method returns true?

Comment: You're looking for [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html): `isNullOrEmpty(s: string | undefined | null): s is string`

Comment: Actually, it would be `isNullOrEmpty(s: string | undefined | null): s is undefined | null`, although that may or may not need to also check for `''` (empty string).

Comment: @crashmstr OK, true but it's just that it's a bit strange to have a type guard for what you *don't* want.

Comment: @VLAZ I know, but that is how the C# does it. I'd just use `if (!!userInput)` here instead of trying to recreate c#.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript refers to code that narrows a type (as in, determines it is a particular subset of its possible type) as “type guards,” for example, `typeof` can be used as a type guard:

```
const userInput = getUserInput();
if (typeof userInput === 'string')
{
    const messageLength = userInput.length; // Typescript has no complaints
}
```

This can work positive or negative:

```
const userInput = getUserInput();
if (typeof userInput !== 'object' && typeof userInput !== 'undefined')
{
    const messageLength = userInput.length; // Typescript has no complaints
}
```

And of course there are a bunch of ways to narrow your types, such as checking for falsy values with `if (userInput)` (though that will reject an empty string, which may be undesirable—you could use `if (userInput || userInput === '')` if you wanted), or `if (userInput !== null && userInput !== undefined)`.

And yes, there are also “user-defined type guards” that allow you define when these things are true. The equivalent here would be:

```
isNullOrEmpty(s: string | undefined | null): s is undefined | null {
  return !s && s !== ''; // or however you want to define it
}

const userInput = getUserInput();
if (!isNullOrEmpty(userInput))
{
    const messageLength = userInput.length; // Typescript has no complaints
}
```

The `s is undefined | null` syntax indicates a user-defined type guard, and replaces your `boolean` return type. The function is still expected to return a `boolean` value, where `true` indicates that the variable has the indicated type (i.e. `undefined | null` here), and `false` indicates that it does not (which will result in the type being narrowed to `string` in this case).

Note that Typescript does **not** check to confirm that the code you have written in the body of the user-defined type guard **actually** proves the value has the type you say it has. From a type-safety perspective, it’s basically the same as casting—the only thing Typescript will check is that the wider type and the narrow type are sufficiently related to one another that it **could be** true. For this reason, it may be considered better to use non-user-defined type guards when possible.